# Passport ReferenceError: err is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I want to do a login Form and I did nearly everything fixed but if I registered successfully and I want to log in, it throws either if the password is correct or incorrect:

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: err is not defined**
So i looked up and the errormessage is this: `bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch => {`
If the username is wrong or doesnt exist it just redirect me with an error message, like I programmed it.
Full controller/passport.js file

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'username' }, (username, password, done) => {
            // Matching
            User.findOne({ username: username })
                .then(user => {
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false)
                    }
                    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        if (isMatch) {
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            return done(null, flase, { message: 'Passwort nicht korrekt' })
                        }
                    }))
                })
        })
    )
    passport.serializeUser( function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser( function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id,function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

I include this module into my routes.js
// Login

```
router.get('/', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('login/index');
})
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '../admin',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    })(req, res, next)
})
```

app.js

```
require('./controller/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I tried to remove the err but then false wouldnt be defined, I looked up the passport docu but I havnt found anything, any ideas?
I use express, passport, passport-local, mongoose

Comment: change the syntax as bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {}, and try again.
This happen because you are not close the bracket so function is considering only single argument which you pass after err argument.

Comment: post complete `stack trace`.

Comment: a yes, now it works, thanks